# Entity framework with many one-to-zero-or-one relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to implement many one-to-zero-or-one relationships in one entity, but I am having problems getting it to work then generating the migration for it.

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? MorningExpenseId { get; set; }
    public int? EveningExpenseId { get; set; }
    public Expense MorningExpense { get; set; }
    public Expense EveningExpense { get; set; }
}

public class Expense
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}
modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
    .HasOptional<Expense>(p => p.MorningExpense)
    .WithRequired(g => g.Invoice);

modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
    .HasOptional<Expense>(p => p.EveningExpense)
    .WithRequired(g => g.Invoice);
```

But I am getting an error of `Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship '...' was not loaded because the type '...' is not available.`.
I also was experimenting with using a primary composite key in the ´Expense´ class like:

```
public enum ExpenseType { Morning, Evening };
public class Expense
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ExpenseType ExpenseType { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

But also no luck with getting it to work. How this should be implemented using Fluent API?

Comment: Ive not needed the use of nullable  
`public int? MorningExpenseId { get; set; }`
`public int? EveningExpenseId { get; set; }`

rather using my example from my git page

`public virtual List<Keyword> Keywords { get; set; }`
       `public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }`

That will link entities to eachother using the virtual keyword

Comment: I just have to comment... using `Id` everywhere is not good from a database perspective. I encourage you to name the `Id` column of a table with the name: `ExpenseId`, `InvoiceId`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In Entity framework, appliation types must match Database types. Relationships must have the virtual keywork.

You must code like this

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MorningExpenseId { get; set; }
    public int EveningExpenseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Expense MorningExpense { get; set; }
    public virtual Expense EveningExpense { get; set; }
}

public class Expense
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have noted that you do not need MorningExpenseId and EveningExpenseId in the Invoice class, as you do not need InvoiceId in the Expense class. Entity framework will take care of the Id's in the relationships.

Comment: You are right I don't need these two id's, but also note that they are nullable because they are optional. Also, the virtual keyword is desirable but not mandatory, unless you want to take advantage of lazy loading. This is a simplified version of the code I am using, so my apologies for these minor "typos".

However, the point with my question is that I don't get the multiple one-to-zero-or-one relationships working, getting the error I pointed out in my post.